# Java String array values to 2D int array

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv, integer

I am a beginner and I have a matrix in a CSV file like this:

0;1;1;0
1;0;1;1
1;1;0;0
0;1;0;0

And I want to import it into a 2D int array so I can do multiplications with it and calculate some stuff for my graph program. This is my code so far:

```
try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line = "";

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] values = line.replaceAll("\\D+","").split(";");

            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0;j< values.length;j++)
                {
                    test[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
                    System.out.print(test[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("****");
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My problem is that it will put all values from the first line into the first [] of the matrix and doesn't put every single value in each []. I tried different approaches but I always have the same outcome. I kindly ask for help.

Edit: I didn't clarify my issue properly. My code takes the first like "0110" and doesn't put each value into each place of the first line of my matrix. It should be test[0][0] has the value 0, test[0][1] has the value 1, test[0][2] has the value 1, test[0][3] has the value 0. And the same for the other lines. But it puts the whole line in [0][0] and also cuts off the first number. So it doesn't have 0110 in that place but 110.

Comment: `replaceAll("\\D+","")` will remove all non digit chars including ; Spliting at ; afterwards will have no effect. Remove that `replaceAll` and use just `line.split(";")`

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an increment variable that can be used to change the row for the matrix. Try the below code:

```
try {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
String line = "";
int rowNumber = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split(";");
    for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
        test[rowNumber][j] = Integer.parseInt(values[j]);
        System.out.print(test[rowNumber][j]);
    }
    rowNumber++;
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("****");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I updated my original post. My problem is that the first line gets put in test[0][0] as a whole and not just the first value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the while loop to deal with each line. Use a variable (`i` below) to remember the line you're in. Then just loop over the splitted line like you alread do, but use the correct index for `values` (`j`, not `i`):

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    String line = "";

    int i = 0; //to remember the line
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = line.split(";");
        for (int j = 0; j<values.length; j++) {
            test[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(values[j]); //use j here, not i!
            System.out.print(test[i][j]);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: @Eritrean I have updated my answer. you need to remove .replaceAll("\\D+","") as it is removing all the semiconlons (';')

Answer (score 0):

- Try using just "i" as index for values, as the inner loop is not
  needed, you read values from csv in line-by-line manner.
- Remove that "replaceAll" method as that might be giving the error!

Code:

```java
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    String line = "";
    int i = -1;    //here i will act as number of lines that have been "read"
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        i+=1;    //incrementing i to increase line count, and move array to next iteration
        String[] values = line.split(";");    //removed replaceAll method
        for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            test[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(values[j]);
            System.out.print(test[i][j]);
        }    //j for loop close
        System.out.println();
    }    //while close
    System.out.println("****");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it still puts a whole line into one array box. Also the first value of the first line and the first value of the last line just disappear.

test[0][0] has 110 in it and test[0][1] until test[0][3] has no values in it. Instead of 0110 being in each place it is cut off and in one place.

Comment: @limetree20 try not using "replaceAll" method. Just split the lines by ";". I will update my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

You know the required size of the matrix. Well that's handy, but what if you didn't? What if the matrix data contained within the CSV file happens to be be of a dynamic size on a regular basis. Are you going to open the file and check every time you want to run your application against a CSV file? Maybe, and maybe you just don't have to for the current situation. It is however, nice to know you can run you application against any sized matrix within any CSV file.

A 2D Array in Java is merely and Array of Arrays. When an array is declared it will be of a fixed size which is good if the CSV file happens to have matrix data contain within it that varies in size from time to time. The following code can get use the number of lines contained within the file:

```
int numOfLines;
try {
    numOfLines = (int) java.nio.file.Files.lines(java.nio.file.Paths
            .get("MatrixData.csv"), java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset()).count();
}
catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

When you are reading in data line, you split that line into a String[] array using:

```
String[] values = line.replaceAll("\\D+","").split(";");
```

This is not good because the `\\D` expression used this way within the `replaceAll()` method will effectively remove all non-digit characters from the data line string and this would also include the delimiter (**;**) used within the data line to separate the individual digits. Your split is not going to do what you really want. It will only provide you with a 4 digit numerical string. It would be better to just do away with the `replaceAll()` method altogether and just do something like:

```
String[] values = line.split("\\s*;\\s*");
```

The expression passed to the `split()` method will handle any number of whitespaces before and or after the delimiter (**if** they exist). Is whitespaces are there, they will not be part of any array element data.

Try the code below. It will process any matrix size within your CSV files (even if the columns [inner Arrays] are of different lengths):

```
String filePath = "MatrixData.csv";
// Get number of data lines in CSV file.
int lineCounter = 0;
try {
    lineCounter = (int) java.nio.file.Files.lines(java.nio.file.Paths
            .get(filePath), java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset()).count();
}
catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
// ---------------------------------------
    
int[][] matrix = new int[lineCounter][]; //Declare & initialize the 2D Array
    
// 'Try With Resources' used here to auto-close the reader and free resources.
try (java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(filePath))) {
    String line = "";
    lineCounter = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.trim();
        if (line.isEmpty()) { continue; } // Skip blank lines (if any).
        /* Split the file lie into a String[] Array then convert 
           it to an int[] array (all in one line using Stream - Java8+).  */
        int[] intValues = java.util.stream.Stream.of(line.split("\\s*;\\s*"))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
        // Copy the new int[] Array into the current row element of the 2D Array.
        matrix[lineCounter] = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(intValues, intValues.length);
        lineCounter++;
    }
} catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
   
    
// Display the Matrix...
for (int[] ary : matrix) {
    String str = java.util.Arrays.toString(ary);
    System.out.println(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1));
}
```